# Is there a way to block set operations on a List?

Tags: java

I have a list of items, and after populating it I want to block any change that might happen. I am trying with `Collections.unmodifiableList`, but it blocks add and remove, but I can still use set. So I am locking for a standard solution like using `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

Any thoughts on this condition?

My code(the code is in another language but I guess it is just to follow the methods):

```
public SerFixo(List<? extends Caracteristica> caracteristicas) {
    this.caracteristicas = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Caracteristica>(caracteristicas.size()));
    setCaracteristicas(caracteristicas);
}

public final void setCaracteristica(Integer indice, Caracteristica caracteristica) {
    this.caracteristicas.set(indice, caracteristica);
}

public final void setCaracteristicas(List<? extends Caracteristica> caracteristicas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < caracteristicas.size(); i++) {
        setCaracteristica(i, caracteristicas.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: please post up your code with error you get so others can help you better

Comment: it is just: list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList` should not permit `set` operations.  Please post your code; it seems much more likely that you're using it wrong somehow.

Comment: You can `extend` any Collections class you like and `@Override` any methods you wish to not do anything. Be careful though, some methods rely on others for their functionality.

Comment: As others have stated, what you explained should work so you probably have a problem in your code. Post it here.

Comment: that seems odd, after my code I can use set(int index, E element)

Comment: You're mistaken. Collections.unmodifiableList() blocks the set() method too, it will throw an UnsupportedOperationException. So please post an example that shows your behavior.

Comment: I am probably wrong so, I will investigate more, as it is just a view, there is probably some function updating the original object. but you guys help a lot, by telling me this does what I was expecting. I can look for something else now.

Comment: Can anyone put this in a answer so I can accept?

Comment: @user123345, It's not my down-vote but I would hazard a guess that it was for not actually including all the required code and information to accurately diagnose or solve your issue. Either that or as you found, your problem was in another area of your program then this would probably qualify it as covered by the Off-Topic Close Reason: "*This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java docs for Collections.unmodifiableCollection says that you can do only read operation.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection)

```
Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified set. This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only"      
access to internal sets. Query operations on the returned set "read through" to the specified set, and attempts to 
modify the returned set, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.
```

So, you will not be able to do set operation on List returned from unmodifiableList and if you try to do this, it will result in UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Also, note that only the List *returned* from unmodifiableList is unmodifiable.

Comment: Finally got it, there was some code in another part of the class modifying the original, and I finally got the  UnsupportedOperationException I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the List in a class and set it to private.
Then you can add methods that allow the access.

```
private List list;
private boolean listIsBlocked = false;    

public void addItem(Object o){
   if(listIsBlocked)return;
   //adding object to list
}
```

This is not a standart solution but also not difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```

`Collections.unmodifiableList()` provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists. Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`. How can you say its modifiable

Comment: It is just a view. it was benign modified elsewhere from the original. I found the problem here.

Comment: Debugging would have prevented you to coming to a wrong conclusion no matters cheers now you learnt something 2dy that you will never forget again in life

Comment: I get why you would say that, but I did my homework, it is just a huge piece of software with probabilistic behavior, so the problem was not evident till I was sure about this doubt. Well... problem solved.